# Как записать вот такой текст RefMahala[district_id] в getParam?

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет есть два селекта
первый

```
<select class="span4 region" name="regionId" id="regionId">
```

второй

```
<select class="span3 rayon" name="RefMahala[district_id]" id="RefMahala_district_id">
```

c первым селектом все норм

```
$regionModel->id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('regionId');
```

со вторым не все ок

```
$model->id = Yii::app()->request->getParam("RefMahala[district_id]");
```

Как правильно прописать сюда getparam что бы все заработало?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в первом Yii просто так не напишешь.
Связанно это с реализацией getParam:

```
public function getParam($name,$defaultValue=null)
{
    return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : (isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $defaultValue);
}
```

Таким образом, сначала нужно получать RefMahala, а потом уже из него искать district_id